# Look at the diagonal elements of a matrix and tell if its indefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Our professor showed us the trick, that if a matrix has positive and negative elements on the diagonal, its automatically indefinite.

After analyzing the script, I think the trick must come from the quadratic form:

$Q_A (a) = x'Ax$

And the quadratic form is called indefinite, if there are vectors for x with $Q_A (a) < 0$ and $Q_A (a) > 0$. So it's always possible to plug in a specific vector, e.g. $x = e_i = [1, 0, 0, 0, ...]$ and get any diagonal element.

But then the professors trick only works for symmetric matrices.

My question am I on the right track? Is this where the trick is coming from? Or is it also possible to apply the trick to any matrix (not necessarily symmetric)?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, we don't define "indefinite" to begin with for matrices that aren't symmetric.

Comment: When you say "the quadratic form $X^TAX$", it is assumed implicitly by 99.9% of people doing mathematics that $A$ is symmetric. If this is not the case, you enter into very deep complications.